# How to remove the black screen that appears between activities when to load data from external server or API?

Tags: android, api, android-fragments, android-activity, splash-screen

I have two activties , the first activity is Splash screen which gets disappears in 4s , before second activity is shown a **black screen appears** for few seconds . I am using https://newsapi.org/ to load data into second activity .As loading data takes time so untill that request comes back from the server the black screen remains on the front and once i have data the second activity is populated with UI .

I am using AsyncTask to do this loading of data in background .But still facing an issue of black screen, I **don't want this black screen** to appears when switching between activities. I have tried to use progress bar both in onCreate of activity associated with fragment and in fragment as well but black screen still appears.

[Splash Screen appears for 4s](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRc6m.jpg)

[Black screen between two activities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtHgc.jpg)

[Second Activity after data is loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjevr.jpg)

**SPLASH ACTIVITY CODE**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView.animate().rotationBy(720).setDuration(3000);
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, homepage.class );
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    },4000);

}
```

}

**FRAGMENT**

```
public class FragmentRecentNews extends Fragment {
View view;
private List<RecentNews> recentNewsList;
NewsRepo newsRepo;
public FragmentRecentNews() {
}
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //recentNews
    newsRepo= new NewsRepo();
    recentNewsList = newsRepo.GetTopHeadlines("https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=au&apiKey=b4fcfc3bfc9c4a8380a83a02b3d0cfc7");
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recentnews_fragment,container,false);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewid);
    RecycleViewAdapter adapter = new RecycleViewAdapter(getActivity(),recentNewsList);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 1));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    return view;
}
```

}

**SECOND ACTIVITY**

```
public class homepage extends AppCompatActivity {
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;
private List<RecentNews> recentNewsList;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_homepage);
   //settanlayout
    tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tablayoutid);
    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpagerid);
    ViewPageAdapter viewPageAdapter = new ViewPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPageAdapter.AddFragment(new FragmentRecentNews(),"Recent News");
    viewPageAdapter.AddFragment(new FragmentNewsSources(),"Sources");
    viewPageAdapter.AddFragment(new FragmentCountries(),"Countries");
    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPageAdapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    //Drawer naviagtion
    mDrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drwaerlayoutid);
    mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawerLayout,R.string.open,R.string.close);
    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
    mToggle.syncState();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    if (mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

**RECYCLERVIEWADAPTER**

```
public class RecycleViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleViewAdapter.MyViewHolder>
```

{

```
private FragmentActivity mContext;
private List<RecentNews> mData;
private  Context context;
public RecycleViewAdapter(FragmentActivity mContext, List<RecentNews> mData) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mData = mData;
}
```

}

```
@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view;
    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    view= mInflater.inflate(R.layout.card_recentnews,parent,false);
    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    holder.title.setText(mData.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.source.setText(mData.get(position).getSourceName());
   // holder.author.setText(mData.get(position).getAuthor());
    holder.date.setText(mData.get(position).getPublishedAt());
    //holder.image.setImageResource(mData.get(position).getUrlToImage());
    Picasso.with(mContext).load(mData.get(position).getUrlToImage()).into(holder.image);
    holder.image.setClipToOutline(true);
    holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = mContext.getSupportFragmentManager();
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, newsdetails.class);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mData.size();
}

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView title;
    TextView source;
   // TextView author;
    TextView date;
    ImageView image;
    Button button;

    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);
        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.titletextview);
        source = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sourcetextview);
       // author = itemView.findViewById(R.id.authortextview);
        date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.datetextview);
        image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.newsimageview);
        button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.detailsbtn);
    }
}
```

}

**Home Page Layout**

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drwaerlayoutid"
    >
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".homepage">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/bg"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">
    </ImageView>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="92dp"
        android:layout_height="73dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/logon"></ImageView>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/appdesc"
        android:textColor="#ffff"
        android:layout_below="@+id/heading"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@+id/icon"
        android:id="@+id/heading"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Awais World News"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textStyle="bold">
    </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        android:id="@+id/tablayoutid"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:tabTextColor="#fff"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="#FFB300"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"

        />
    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/viewpagerid"/>
</LinearLayout>
    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:menu="@menu/menu"
        android:layout_gravity="start">
    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Styles.XML**

```
    <resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your network call make before view created in your FragmentRecentNews.
Please, try to do next steps:
1. onCreateView must contain only ui creation steps, like

```
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recentnews_fragment,container,false);
return view
```

2. create override onViewCreated method of fragment and paste your api call code there

You see the black screen, because onCreateView do a lot of work, and fragment can not be drawed.

```
public class FragmentRecentNews extends Fragment {
    View view;
    private List<RecentNews> recentNewsList;
    NewsRepo newsRepo;
    public FragmentRecentNews() {
    }
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recentnews_fragment,container,false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        newsRepo= new NewsRepo();
        recentNewsList = newsRepo.GetTopHeadlines("https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=au&apiKey=b4fcfc3bfc9c4a8380a83a02b3d0cfc7");
        RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewid);
        RecycleViewAdapter adapter = new RecycleViewAdapter(getActivity(),recentNewsList);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 1));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried removing api call from onCreateView  but the problem still persisits .

Comment: Please, give us R.layout.activity_homepage and your activity theme style

Comment: I have added both files in the questions please review.

Comment: @MuhammadAwais, it seems, like one of your layout (fragment or container-activity) or one of inner layouts (Drawer layout,  Linear layout etc) have black background. Your theme is good, it has light background. But some of the components has its own dark background. What do you need to do...  Try to change background resourse of inner layouts  (Drawer layout,  Linear layout etc) and find main point of problem. Also, please, paste your colors.

Comment: Well God knows tried alot of solution but all in vain . Actually if i used dummy data means do not load data from the internet then the black screen does not appears. But when there is a delay in data loading then this occurs.

Comment: it's because you need to move your api call to method, which will be called AFTER view created, as I said it in this answer. For EACH fragment in your activity view pager. When you create your View Pager each fragment try to get data from network. It slows down your screen apearance. Try to put your  api call in proper methods for each fragment, which based on one activity.

Comment: Here is the link to project . if you can help out it would be highly appericated . https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tjzC9zo4oarGHc7xmHFFFC9i9M_zL9W2/view?usp=sharing

Comment: can't beleive pasted the same code but still the issue i same.

Comment: Maybe it's better to show progress when your Async Task works.

Comment: Tried that as well but black screen appears first and then loading start.

Comment: Do you test it on real device or only on avd?

Comment: Tested on both , results are identical.

Comment: The main issue is that when i tried to add a progress dialog irrespective of it added on fragment or activity associated with fragment or Async task the black screen still appears as it was before.

Comment: Try to put your network call in onStart method of your fragment=)

Comment: Your problem is in thread management. `String result = downloadTask.execute(url).get();` blocks your screen and you see that your fragment is not drawed.

Comment: Try to use non-blocking call (use loaders or inner asyncTask in your fragment). Or just simplify it with rxandroid

Comment: I send you solution with these libraries